# Error:(15, 23) error: cannot find symbol method setTint(Drawable,int)

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am importing eclipse project to android studio, in eclipse it works fine but in android studio it has problem with setTint.

here is my drawablecompat setting:

```
public static void tintWidget(Context ctx, View view, int color) {
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = view.getBackground();
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, ctx.getResources().getColor(color));
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
}
```

with DrawableCompat.setTintList also did not work, error on setTintList

what is the correct code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have a dependency missing on app compat v4, try adding it to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

Or whatever SDK version you need instead of `22.2.0`

Take a look at: https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/eclipse-transition-guide.html#dependencies